# Error with MASM sorting

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I'm working on an assignment using MASM and Irvine's library. In this step of the program I'm trying to sort the received array, but I'm having trouble with the implementation.

```
ordr_array  PROC
    pushad
    mov     ebp, esp
    mov     edx, [ebp+40]   ; array value
    mov     ebx, 0          ; array position
    ; [ebp+36]  ; length of input_n

    mov     eax, [ebp+36]

    ; counts up to ecx
    mov     eax, 0
    looper:
        inc     eax         ; k++
        mov     ecx, eax
        inc     ecx         ; j = k + 1
        inner_looper:
            push    eax     ; we need these registers,
            push    ecx     ; save them
            mov     eax, [edx+4*eax]    ; move our values into our registers for comparison
            mov     ecx, [edx+4*ecx]
            cmp     eax, ecx

            jge     inner_looper_end

            mark: ; array[j] > array[i]
                mov     ebx, ecx ; put the inner counter value (j) to swap with the outer (i)

            inner_looper_end:
                pop     ecx     ; restore registers 
                pop     eax     ; ecx and eax

                inc     ecx
                cmp     ecx, [ebp+36]
                jl      inner_looper    ; if we're done with the inner loop, just fall out 

        looper_end:         ; finish looper

            ; exchange code

            push    [edx+4*eax]
            push    [edx+4*ecx]
            call    exchangeElements

            ; end exchange code

            ; see if we need to go again
            inc     eax
            inc     eax                 ; the '+ 1' then '- 1' was the best way I could think of doing '< result - 1' from memory
            cmp     eax, [ebp+36]
            dec     eax
            jl      looper

    popad
    ret     8
ordr_array  ENDP
```

the exchange function called is:

```
exchangeElements    PROC
    pushad

    mov     eax, [ebp+36]    ;to be swapped
    mov     ebx, [ebp+40]    ;to be swapped

    push    [eax]
    push    [ebx]
    pop     [eax]    ;this should swap it
    pop     [ebx]    ;this should swap it

    popad       
    ret 8
exchangeElements    ENDP
```

A shove in the correct direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You haven't explained what the problem is, but it looks like you're passing the arguments to your swap function by value and then treating the arguments as if they were addresses inside the function.

Comment: @Michael: I'm getting an error from the call to exchange elements.  It's just a crash message, nothing particularly useful.

Answer (score 0):

The attempt has failed ;-) Amongst others:

- You begin the outer loop with `inc eax` which means that you start it with EAX=1.
- You take `EAX` and `ECX` as index of the element and as its value and get confused.
- It looks like you are messing the length of the array and its last index.
- `exchangeElements` gets quite random values, but needs the address of an element and the address of the smallest value behind.

I recommend to solve the problem first in a higher programming language until the algorithm works. I suppose you wanted to program something like this:

**PHP-CLI**

```
<?php
$A = "Jacobm001";
$A = str_split ($A, 1);
$L = count($A);

ordr_array ($A,$L);
printf("%s\n",print_r($A,true));


function ordr_array (&$A, $L)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < ($L-1); ++$i)
    {   $B = $A[$i]; $bb = $i;
        for ($j = ($i+1); $j < $L; ++$j)
        {
            if ($A[$j] < $B)
            {
                $B = $A[$j];
                $bb = $j;
            }
        }
        exchangeElements ($A[$i],$A[$bb]);
    }
}

function exchangeElements (&$A, &$B)
{
    $T = $A;
    $A = $B;
    $B = $T;
}

?>
```

**Python**

```
def ordr_array (A, L):
    # outer loop
    for i in range (0,L-1):
        B = A[i]
        bb = i

        # inner loop
        for j in range (i+1, L):
            if (A[j] < B):
                B = A[j]
                bb = j

        # exchangeElements
        A[i], A[bb] = A[bb], A[i]

A = ['J','a','c','o','b','m','0','0','1']
L = len (A)
ordr_array (A,L)
print (A)
```

**C99**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void exchangeElements (char* A, char* B)
{
    char T = *A;
    *A = *B;
    *B = T;
}

void ordr_array (char A[], size_t L)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < (L-1); i++)
    {
        char B = A[i];
        size_t bb = i;

        for (size_t j = i+1; j < L; j++)
        {
            if (A[j] < B)
            {
                B = A[j];
                bb = j;
            }
        }

        exchangeElements (&A[i], &A[bb]);
    }
}

int main ( void )
{
    char A[] = "Jacobm001";
    size_t L = strlen (A);

    ordr_array (A, L);

    printf ("%s\n",A);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm glad I didn't find Haskell or Brainfuck in your profile :-)

If the algorithm works, you can convert point by point in assembler. The best thing is, you take the C program. Malicious tongues say that C is a high level assembly language. Do not ignore the features of the used assembler and library.

**MASM & IRVINE32**

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.DATA
    arr DD 'J','a','c','o','b','m','0','0','1'

.CODE
main PROC
    push LENGTHOF arr                   ; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/operator-lengthof
    push OFFSET arr                     ; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/operator-offset?
    call ordr_array

    mov ecx, LENGTHOF arr
    lea esi, arr
    @@:
    lodsd
    call WriteChar                      ; Irvine: Writes a single character in AL to standard output
    loop @B
    mov al, 0Dh                         ; New Line
    call WriteChar

    exit
main ENDP

ordr_array PROC STDCALL, A:PTR, L:DWORD ; STDCALL & arguments forces MASM to produce `RET x`
LOCAL bb:DWORD
    pushad                              ; PUSHAD is elegant, but not effective ;-)
    mov edx, A                          ; Address of array
    dec L                               ; Convert length of array to number of last index

    xor eax, eax
    .WHILE (eax < L)                    ; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/dot-while
        mov esi, [edx+4*eax]
        mov ebx, esi
        mov ecx, eax
        mov bb, ecx
        .WHILE (ecx < L)                ; Inner loop
            inc ecx
            mov edi, [edx+4*ecx]
            .IF (edi < esi && edi < ebx)    ; Looking for the minimum
                mov ebx, edi                ; Save value of minimum
                mov bb, ecx                 ; Save index of minimum
            .ENDIF
        .ENDW                           ; End of inner loop

        mov ecx, bb
        lea ecx, [edx+4*ecx]            ; B = Address of minimum
        push ecx
        lea ecx, [edx+4*eax]            ; A = Address of outer loop element
        push ecx
        call exchangeElements

;       mov ecx, bb                     ; exchangeElements inline
;       mov [edx+4*eax], ebx
;       mov [edx+4*ecx], esi

        inc eax
    .ENDW                               ; End of outer loop

    popad
    ret                                 ; = `ret 8` due to STDCALL & arguments
ordr_array ENDP

exchangeElements PROC STDCALL USES eax ecx esi edi, A:PTR, B:PTR
    mov esi, A
    mov edi, B
    mov eax, [esi]
    mov ecx, [edi]
    mov [esi], ecx
    mov [edi], eax
    ret                                 ; = `ret 8` due to STDCALL & arguments
exchangeElements    ENDP

END main
```